# ImageScaleToFit - how to implement?

Tags: image, coldfusion, railo, cfimage

I'm new to [Railo](http://getrailo.org), moving away from ColdFusion 8 where my site used to used to use cfx_imagecr3.

I believe Railo has [ImageScaleToFit](http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/3-1-Functions%3aImageScaleToFit) but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly or if I need to add some kind of class/component? I've added it between a cfscript but i get 'invalid variable declaration' which doest make any sense to me. Any help appreciated.

I'm running railo-4.0.0.013 on ubuntu 12.04

```
<cfscript>
        imageScaletoFit('/home/images/testimage.jpg','90','114','highestPerformance');
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first load the image into a variable, then use that variable name inside ImageScaletoFit, like so:

```
<cfimage name="ImgVariable" source="/home/images/testimage.jpg" />

<cfset imageScaletoFit(ImgVariable,'90','114','highestPerformance') />
```

(This isn't specific to Railo - the function exists and works the same way in CF8+)

Comment: Thank you for your time, i've never used cfimage and didnt know imageScaletoFit worked in conjunction with cfimage